# Find whether 1D sub-array is in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a data-array like:

```
all = [[1,-1], [1,0], [1,1], [2,-1], [2,0], [2,1]]  etc.
```

It has about 4000 pairs in it, but typically fewer on the order of a few hundred.

I need to find whether a two-valued array already exists in this large data-array, eg.
does `[1,1]` exist in the array?

So the function I need should act something like this:

```
isValid( all, [1,1] )
>>> True

isValid( all, [1,100] )
>>> False
```

I couldn't get the numpy functions `isin()` or `in1d()` to do this for me.  The one function I did find works, for lists, is:

```
all.index( [1,1] )
>> True
```

but when the arg is **not** in the `all` array, I have to try/catch a `ValueError` and then return `False` - acceptable for now, but not ideal.

Comment: Maybe `[1,1] in lst`? By the way, don't name your variable `all`, which is the name of a built-in function. I've used `lst` instead of `all`.

Comment: What does this have the do with numpy? What you've shown is a *list* not an array

Comment: nothing to with with numpy, apart from numpy being one module that might help - converting to array would be acceptable, as the 2nd answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple array lookup like this:

```
a = [[1,-1], [1,0], [1,1], [2,-1], [2,0], [2,1]]

[2,0] in a # True
[2,3] in a # False
```

or

```
a.index([2,0]) # result: 4
a.index([3,5]) # throw error, use try catch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy installed, you can use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) to find the indices of 1d array in a 2d numpy array and check if the return result

```
import numpy as np

def isValid(arr, val):
   return len(np.where(np.prod(arr == val, axis = -1))[0]) != 0

all_items = np.array([[1,-1], [1,0], [1,1], [2,-1], [2,0], [2,1]] )
search1 = isValid(all_items, [1,1] ) # True
search2 = isValid(all_items, [1,100] ) # False
```